# How to find all subsets of a set using java with custom format for output

Tags: java, algorithm, set, subset

I am trying to write a code to find all the possible subsets of a set using java and here is my code :

```
public static void printSubSets(Set set){
    int n = set.size();
    ArrayList<String> strings = new ArrayList<>();
    Object[] chars = set.toArray();
    for (int i = 0; i < (1<<n); i++)
    {
        String string = "";
        string += "{";
        for (int j = 0; j < n; j++)
            if ((i & (1 << j)) > 0)
                string += chars[j].toString() + ",";
        string+= "}";
        if (string.length() > 2){
            StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder(string);
            stringBuilder.deleteCharAt(string.lastIndexOf(","));
            strings.add(stringBuilder.toString());
        }
        else
        {
            strings.add(string);
        }
    }
    strings.sort((s1, s2) -> s1.length() - s2.length());
    for (int i = 0; i < strings.size(); i++) {
        if (i == strings.size() - 1){
            System.out.println(strings.get(i) + "");
        }
        else{
            System.out.print(strings.get(i) + " , ");
        }
    }
}
```

I used the above function to find all the subsets and it works fine
and here is my main method :

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
    int row1 = 0;
    int row2 = 0;
    Set A = new TreeSet();
    Set B = new TreeSet();
    row1 = scanner.nextInt();
    for (int i = 0; i < row1; i++) {
        A.add(scanner.nextInt());
    }
    row2 = scanner.nextInt();
    for (int i = 0; i < row2; i++) {
        B.add(scanner.nextInt());
    }
    System.out.print("A -> ");
    Main.printSubSets(A);
    System.out.print("B -> ");
    Main.printSubSets(B);
}
```

for input :

```
4
1 2 3 4
3
3 5 7
```

and the output is :

```
A -> {} , {1} , {2} , {3} , {4} , {1,2} , {1,3} , {2,3} , {1,4} , 
{2,4} , {3,4} , {1,2,3} , {1,2,4} , {1,3,4} , {2,3,4} , {1,2,3,4}
B -> {} , {3} , {5} , {7} , {3,5} , {3,7} , {5,7} , {3,5,7}
```

but there is a problem. I want it to be like this :

```
A -> {} , {1} , {2} , {3} , {4} , {1,2} , {1,3} , {1,4} , {2,3} , 
{2,4} , {3,4} , {1,2,3} , {1,2,4} , {1,3,4} , {2,3,4} , {1,2,3,4}
```

I mean that I want {1,4} to precede the {2,3}
I will be glad if you help solve this

Answer (score 0):

May I suggest a different solution to find all the subsets of a Set:

```
    Set<Integer> mySet = new HashSet<Integer>();
    mySet.add(1);
    mySet.add(2);
    mySet.add(3);
    Set<Set<Integer>> powerSet = powerSet(mySet);
    LinkedList<Set<Integer>> ans = new LinkedList<>();

    for(Set<Integer> element : powerSet){
        for(Set<Integer> el : powerSet){
            if(el.size() == element.size() && !ans.contains(el)){
                ans.add(el);
            }
        }
    }
    System.out.println(ans.toString());
```

and

```
public static <Integer> Set<Set<Integer>> powerSet(Set<Integer> pSet) {
    Set<Set<Integer>> sets = new HashSet<Set<Integer>>();
    if (pSet.isEmpty()) {
        sets.add(new HashSet<Integer>());
        return sets;
    }
    List<Integer> integersList = new ArrayList<Integer>(pSet);
    Integer head = integersList.get(0);
    Set<Integer> restSet = new HashSet<Integer>(integersList.subList(1, integersList.size()));
    for (Set<Integer> set : powerSet(restSet)) {
        Set<Integer> newSet = new HashSet<Integer>();
        newSet.add(head);
        newSet.addAll(set);
        sets.add(newSet);
        sets.add(set);
    }
    return sets;
}
```

And the output is:

```
[[], [1], [2], [3], [1, 2], [1, 3], [2, 3], [1, 2, 3]]
```

You can try it with more integers. The method is the same even if you read integers from the console.

Comment: thanks for your response but there is still problem with that
for input with 1 to 4 inputs it works fine but for a set with 5 members it does not work properly
Do you suggest any other method?

Comment: See again the answer I gave I have changed the answer so ans is not anymore Set but a LinkedList. The output is what you are waiting for.

Comment: I tried with the new code and the problem is still the same
for input 1, 2,3,4,5 we have the following output :
[[], [1], [2], [3], [4], [5], [1, 2], [1, 3], [1, 4], [2, 3], [1, 5], [2, 4], [2, 5], [3, 4], [3, 5], [4, 5], [1, 2, 3], [1, 2, 4], [1, 2, 5], [1, 3, 4], [1, 3, 5], [2, 3, 4], [1, 4, 5], [2, 3, 5], [2, 4, 5], [3, 4, 5], [1, 2, 3, 4], [1, 2, 3, 5] ...
and as you see  [1, 2], [1, 3], [1, 4], [2, 3], [1, 5]  is not in the right order
I mean that it must be like below 
[1, 2], [1, 3], [1, 4], [1, 5]
I don't know how to solve this